# Installing Memory Sanitizer and Leak Sanitizer into clang compiler

Tags: c, memory-management, memory-leaks

I have downloaded LLVM from Home-brew, but I am still unable to use -fsanitize=memory when checking for memory issues in C. I am getting the following error: `clang: error: unsupported option '-fsanitize=memory' for target 'arm64-apple-darwin21.2.0'`. What do I need to do in order use the Memory Sanitizer as well as Leak Sanitizer on my M1 Mac Pro? (macOS Monterey)

Answer (score 2):

MemorySanitizer is supported on the following OS:
Linux
NetBSD
FreeBSD

Comment: https://clang.llvm.org/docs/MemorySanitizer.html#supported-platforms